# sprintf undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, c

I can't seem to find info on this:  Does using wrong format specifiers in `sprintf` cause UB like in `printf`?

and I'll ask also here is following UB?

```
unsigned int x = 5;
printf("%d",x);
```

or this:

```
unsigned char x = 5;
printf("%d",x);
```

Comment: One question at a time please.

Comment: Using the wrong format specifiers in `sprintf()` causes UB just like in `printf()`, and the same is true for all other the members of the `printf` family of functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does using wrong format specifiers in `sprintf` cause UB like in `printf`?

Yes. All the `*printf` specifiers are defined the same (in the `fprintf` section, actually).

> and I'll ask also here is following UB?
>
> ```
> unsigned int x = 5;
> printf("%d",x);
> ```

This is technically UB. `%d` expects an `int` argument, and "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined." (WG14 N1570, 7.21.6.1/p9; I don't think C11 changed anything here compared to C99). `unsigned int` is not `int`. In practice, you can probably get away with it.

> or this:
>
> ```
> unsigned char x = 5;
> printf("%d",x);
> ```

This is not UB if and only if `unsigned char` is promoted to `int` by integer promotion, which is usually the case.

Comment: It is not necessarily true that `unsigned char` is promoted to `int`.

Comment: @KerrekSB "which is usually the case".

Comment: @T.C.:now this is confusing, seems you provide different answer than Kerrek SB above

Comment: @dmcr_code: I deleted my answer; T.C. has the right quote about the type having to match exactly. Moreover, you can test statically how `unsigned char` is promoted (e.g. by checking limits).

Comment: @dmcr_code: Just to record the salient point of my answer: When you have a function with variable arguments (`...`) and you call it with any kind of `int`, then you can use `va_arg` to read any other kind of `int` from the argument list and it is not UB. (And similar for functions without prototype, in C.) But `printf` is more restrictive than that.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I don't get how to check that (the limit). But thanks for the info so far, I will have to be careful with printf and similar cases in future. would be nice if there is some resource on internet which well explains all this stuff

Comment: @dmcr_code: The promotion rules are expressed in terms of representable values. If an `int` can represent all the values that an `unsigned char` can, then the promotion is to `int`; otherwise it's to `unsigned int` (which *must* be able to hold all values of an `unsigned char`).

Comment: @KerrekSB: this is tricky I will give it more through investigation later (somewhere I read passing unsigned char in printf which has %u can also be UB since unsigned char might be promoted to int?) so this is getting confusing then.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I would need time to research your counter-question (to my quote of ISO/IEC 9899:2011, §6.5.2.2 Function calls, ¶6 in the comments to your now deleted answer), but the quoted material _suggests_ that passing a `signed int` where an `unsigned int` is expected, or vice versa, doesn't automatically and unconditionally lead to UB.  I need to look hard at the larger scope (the earlier portion of ¶6 in particular) to be sure how/whether it applies to `printf()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I think at some point I will just figure out *exactly* which format specifier to use with which type and stick only to that!.

Comment: @dmcr_code: that is much the simplest approach.  Note that the `<inttypes.h>` header can help improve the portability of (at least some) printing -- in practice, it helps enormously with the most confusing of the types, the integer types.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I'm sure that regarding general argument passing you're absolutely right, but `printf` itself makes an explicit requirement (quoted in this answer) that the argument types must match exactly.

Comment: @dmcr_code: Yeah, that's a good point, that could indeed happen. Best to use `%u` and call it with `(unsigned int)x`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: thanks for tip not sure how to use that header though. Ok just remembered I used sprintf somewhere in my code and asked. but i think my program has been working ok so far, so I must have not confused the types, but I will double check.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I'm not sure whether there's any wriggle room or not; §7.21.6.1 **The `printf` function** ¶9 does not leave much wriggle room.  I will note that §7.16.1.1 **The `va_arg` macro** ¶2 would bolster my case better than §6.5.2.2 ¶6 were it not for §7.21.6.1 ¶9.  It doesn't pay to lie to `printf()`, so being accurate is undoubtedly best.  However, passing a signed value where unsigned is expected or vice versa when the value is in the common range will _probably_ work (even usually work), but relying on that is fraught (not least because of ensuring the value is in the common range).

Comment: @dmcr_code: in the short term, you probably don't need to use `<inttypes.h>`.  If you start to worry about portability between 32-bit and 64-bit systems (or other more esoteric mixes of platforms), then you will need to think about how to code format strings so that they remain usable between the multiple platforms without code duplication.  It isn't a trivial proposition, especially if you have format strings coming from 'files' (for internationalization of an application, for example).